# TFS Cannot complete Product Backlog Item because there is no transition from "Committed" with the action "Microsoft.VSTS.Action.CheckIn"

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

We have an on-prem TFS 2018 Update 2 instance and are running into an issue during this workflow:

- Create a product backlog item
- Write code
- Create a pull request and associate the product backlog item with it
- Complete the code review and mark the pull request as approved
- Click "Complete" and the pull request is merged into master. Associated items *should be* marked as Done but are not and instead their State doesn't change.

I just noticed this yellow error message popup after clicking Approve:

> VS1640134: Cannot complete Product Backlog Item 10275 because there is no transition from 'Committed' with the action "Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin". [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/automate-field-assignments-state-transition-reason?view=vsts)
>
> (1 more work item will not be completed)

I can't find anything on that error code **VS1640134** and we're just using regular agile scrum work items without any added or custom fields.

The message referenced this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/automate-field-assignments-state-transition-reason?view=vsts

VSTS twitter support pointed me to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Fwork-items%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts#track-progress

But neither seem to explain how to resolve the problem. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**
After forgetting about this problem it was pushed back up on my agenda. I reviewed the answer that's now marked as accepted and that process generally worked. I made the following edits to the default items:

*Project Backlog Item XML:*

```
        <TRANSITION from="New" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
          <ACTIONS>  
            <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
          </ACTIONS> 
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Approved" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
          <ACTIONS>  
            <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
          </ACTIONS> 
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Committed" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
          <ACTIONS>  
            <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
          </ACTIONS> 
        </TRANSITION>
```

*Bug XML:*

```
        <TRANSITION from="New" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
          <ACTIONS>  
            <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
          </ACTIONS> 
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Approved" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
          <ACTIONS>  
            <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
          </ACTIONS> 
        </TRANSITION>
        <TRANSITION from="Committed" to="Done">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Work finished" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
          <ACTIONS>  
            <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
          </ACTIONS> 
        </TRANSITION>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the provided link, you need to export your PBI's XML, and in the transition "from Committed" to another state you need to add these lines:

```
 <ACTIONS>  
  <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
 </ACTIONS>
```

For example:

```
 <TRANSITION from="Committed" to="Ready To Build">  
   <REASONS>
     ....
   </REASONS>
      <ACTIONS>  
      <ACTION value="microsoft.vsts.actions.checkin"/>  
      </ACTIONS>  
</TRANSITION>
```

Then you need to import back the XML file into the TFS.

For more information about export/import: [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018)

Comment: `witadmin exportwitd /collection:https://your-tfs-server.com/tfs/yourcollectionName /p:YourProject /n:"Product Backlog Item" /f:"C:/temp/pbi.xml"`
 edit the file, then 
`witadmin importwitd /collection:https://your-tfs-server.com/tfs/yourcollectionName /p:YourProject /f:"C:/temp/pbi.xml"`